# how to filter and add conditional statements of the data coming from json local file in react native using map

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, dictionary, filter

the thing is i have a json file and a need to know how to filter my data result depending on the city that i want to show.
i have already tried working with filter like this:

```
  agadir_medicineList() {

    return this.state.data.filter(data.city === "Agadir").map(medicine => (
      <Medicine_list key={medicine.title} medicine={medicine}  />
    ));
```

but it didn't work.
this is my json file data:

```
]
{
    title: "Dr. kareem",
    city: "Inezgane",
    speciality: "Généraliste",
    tel: "tel:000000000",
},
{
    title: "Dr. Ahmed",
    city: "Agadir",
    speciality: "Généraliste",
    tel: "tel:000000000",
},
{
    title: "Dr. Jack",
    city: "Ait Melloul",
    speciality: "Généraliste",
    tel: "tel:000000000",
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method expects a callback function as first parameter. Your code should look like:

```
agadir_medicineList() {
    return this.state.data.filter(data => data.city === "Agadir").map(medicine => (
      <Medicine_list key={medicine.title} medicine={medicine}  />
    ));
```

Comment: yes thank you so much, that's how exactly i did it using a `const`.


```agadir_medicineList() {
    const agadir = this.state.list_allMedicine.filter((agadir) =>{
                             return agadir.city === 'Agadir'});
    return  agadir.map(medicine => (
                <Medicine_listDetail key={medicine.title} medicine={medicine} 
                 /> ));
  }
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to add `setState.isLoading: false` inside this function !!??